# How to get barometric pressure iOS

Tags: ios, weather, iphone-6

From what I know, the new iPhone 6/Plus have a barometer that will give us the value of the air pressure. How do I do this? There's little resources I can find.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is part of the Core Motion Framework. It exposes two new class [CMAltimeter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMAltimeter_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CMAltimeter) and [CMAltitudeData](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMAltitudeData_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CMAltitudeData) which you can use to determine the barometric pressure.

> Core Motion provides two new classes ([CMAltimeter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMAltimeter_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CMAltimeter) and [CMAltitudeData](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMAltitudeData_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CMAltitudeData))
>   which allow you to access the barometer on the iPhone 6 and iPhone 6
>   Plus. On these two devices, you can also use a CMMotionActivity object
>   to determine whether the user is on a bicycle.

Source: [Apple Developer Center](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS8.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014205-SW1)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but how exactly do I implement it? I cannot find any method for getting pressure and altitude. @atrljoe

Comment: @zbz.lvlv If you look at the CMAltitudeData class there is a property for the pressure `@property(readonly, nonatomic) NSNumber *pressure`. It should be as simple as using that property to return the pressure. This class isnt accessed directly though which is why you need CMAltimeter.

Comment: I don't really understand the documentation. How does creating a NSNumber gets the pressure? I'm sorry for this but I'm rather new to iOS programming @atrljoe.

Comment: I've figured it out you just need to call alloc on the class. Thanks for your time and effort!

Answer (score 1):

Attention: It seams, that with the iOS 10.0.1 it is no more possible to detect if a pressure sensor is available e.g. on the iPad Pro. I have written a bug report to Apple.